# Problems with centering

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, uibutton

In my program, I create a scroll view and then I programmatically create a bunch of buttons in my code. The problem is the buttons don't center in the code. This is the code I'm using:

```
let i = num - 1
let padding = 10
let h = Int(scrollView.frame.height) - (padding * 2)
let w = h
let button = UIButton()

button.frame = CGRect(x: padding * (i + 1) + (i * w), y: padding, width: w, height: h)
```

Comment: Where is this code? How do the buttons actually appear? How should they appear? Should be they be centered vertically or horizontally?

Comment: This code is in a create button function inside of the view controller. I want the buttons to be centered vertically, but in the code, they are above the center.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found out my problem: I put two different padding values when creating the scrollView and the buttons, so it became offset.